# GridView CheckBox If checked is defaulted but users unchecks, on postback checkbox is still checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with 5 grids.  The first field in each grid is a  within a template.  Upon pageload and if not postback i set this checked box .checked based on return from database.

If the user unchecks the checkbox, this checkeboxed.checked = false is not being preserved on postback.  Interesting enough, if the user checks an unchecked box, that change does make it over on post back.  Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions on how to fix. Thank you!

```
<asp:GridView ID="commonAdultClinicReferrals" CssClass="Report" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            Width="270" AllowPaging="false" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="DataAlternateRow"
                            CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" EmptyDataText="No Results."
                            DataKeyNames="Id,Name,Description,FollowUpList"  OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <center>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="selectedRowCb" runat="server"  />
                                        </center>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Common Adult Clinic Referrals" ItemStyle-Width="250"
                                    ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Class:

```
public class FollowUp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool FollowUpList { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public FollowUp(int id, string name, string description, bool followUpList, bool selected)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.FollowUpList = followUpList;
        this.Selected = selected;
    }
}
```

DataBind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        hdnWindowClose.Value = string.Empty;

        loadUi();
    }


}

private void loadUi()
{

    _adultServices = GetFollowUps(2, true);
    adultClinicReferrals.DataSource = _adultServices;
    adultClinicReferrals.DataBind();
```

}

Setting Checkbox checked:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && !Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("selectedRowCb"));
        FollowUp fol = (FollowUp)e.Row.DataItem;
        bool selected = fol.Selected;

        cb.Checked = selected;

    }

}
```

On Save:

```
 protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetSelectedCodes(followUpAppointments);
    GetSelectedCodes(adultClinicReferrals);
    GetSelectedCodes(commonAdultClinicReferrals);
    GetSelectedCodes(otherAdultClinicReferrals);
    GetSelectedCodes(pediClinicReferrals);

    hdnWindowClose.Value = "yes";


    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string str = js.Serialize(_selectedServices);

    hdnFollowUp.Value = str;
    SetNotePickCodes();
}
```

At last inside GetSelectedCodes()   Is where checkbox.check state does not work if that check box was defaulted to true:

```
private void GetSelectedCodes(GridView gv)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[i];
        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("selectedRowCb")).Checked;

        if (isChecked)
        {
            int id = (Int32)gv.DataKeys[i]["Id"];
            string name = gv.DataKeys[i]["Name"].ToString();
            string description = gv.DataKeys[i]["Description"].ToString();
            bool followup = (bool)gv.DataKeys[i]["FollowUpList"];

            _selectedServices.Add(new FollowUp(id,name,description,followup,true));
        }


    }
```

the if (isChecked) branch is getting executed, when I do not expect it to. For example when the user had unchecked a checkbox.  My databind is done only on page load if not a page.postback.

Again many thanks for any help.

Thank you,

Jay

Comment: Did you check whether the method "loadUi()" is not called anywhere else in the page?

Comment: Good suggestion,  Yes I did. It's only called once.

Comment: Can you check if the form key came in the request? Like Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$gridView$ctl02$selectedRowCb"]. The key would only exist if the checkbox was indeed checked, where the keyvalue would be "on". If it was unchecked on the client, the checkbox UniqueId should not come on the request.

Comment: Thanks to both Praveen and Mt. Schneiders.  While trying the Request.Form, I found my bug.  I had goofed up the groups of checkboxes that had same value in DB,  so while i was checking one checkbox I was really checking two checkboxes.  I have some other grid views in a hidden div to be displayed upon patient type.  I removed the loading of these hidden grids (should have done in the first place) This fixed the issue.  Thanks again for your suggestions.